# Rolling up the status of an excel column to a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am an intermediate excel user at best.   I've looked everywhere back can't seem to be able to find this specific formula how-to.

What I need to do is in a status worksheet I have a series of tasks that I'm rolling up.  I need Cell D2 to change to highlighted green and labeled complete once cells D6 thru D17 are labeled Complete.  What formula should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a countif.  This compares it to the number of rows in the range you could also just put in =11.

> =if(countif(D6:17,"Complete")=rows(D6:D17),"Complete","Not Complete")

For turning it green just use conditional formatting if that cell is Complete make it green.

Comment: Isn't this a 3D formula? if so it requires CTRL+ENTER to get it be activated/calculated.

Comment: One more note: Using "Complete" and "Not complete" as basis for the calculation depends on *spelling*, which might be error prone. But then, you could use a custom list and make it be a 'drop-down' with 'Data > Validty' in LibreOffoce or 'Validation' in Excel.

Comment: no countif is a built in function not an array function so it doesn't need ctrl+shift+enter.  I would assume that the cells would have complete added using a function to put it in so spelling shouldn't be an issue.  I just prefer to have the cell display what is actually stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

Apply a custom format to display "Complete" for a cell content of 1 (the number) for D2, and D6:D17
Then make D2 be "=(sum(D6:D17)=rows(D6:D17))"

Fill in 1 (or calculate the value) for complete jobs in D6 to D17, make them be 0 otherwise.

The coloring is a conditional format thing. formula "=(D2=1)" or possibly "=(D2=TRUE)"

Comment: I think it should be rows(D6:D17) as they are all in a single column.  Also I'm not a big fan of formatting like that as it tends to screw up users who expect to see what the actual cell value is.  If nobody else is using the sheet or touching those cells it's not a big deal.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed ROWS() it should be/changed. Well, formatting is for your eyes not for calculations ;-)

Comment: With some tweaking (possibly) one could use 100% instead of "1" for complete.